# Python self function

Tags: python, function, self

I am modifying some Python code. In this code there is a class called Proxy which has a function "run" that is executed.

```
import flask
import gevent

class: Proxy
    def __init(self):
        ''' 
        *stuff*
        '''

        flask_app = Flask(__name__)

        self.run = lambda: (
            self.logger.critical('LISTENING %s%s' % (host, port)) or
            flask_app.run(host=host, port=port) 
        )

proxy = Proxy()
proxy.run()
```

I need to change the `self.run = lambda: ('...')` so that `proxy.run()` executes the following code:

```
http = WSGIServer(('', 8000), flask_app)
http.serve_forever()
```

How do I do this? I don't think I need a lambda expression and I should be using something else. How do I make `proxy.run()` execute the 2 lines of code from above? Assume I have all the proper dependencies imported and that the Proxy class functions as intended. Thanks in advance for your help.

I tried the following:

```
def run():
    http = WSGIServer(('', 8000), flask_app)
    http.serve_forever()
```

Then I tried `proxy.run()` and I get the error:

```
AttributeError: 'Proxy" object has no attribute 'run'
```

Comment: You're eliding too much context. `self` isn't a function; it's an _argument_ used for methods, so it only works inside a method. And `class: Proxy` isn't valid syntax at all.

Comment: That said -- a lambda is just a function. `def run(): ...` will create a `run` function, just like `run = lambda: ...` does (though in a class context, it's probably more appropriate to create a method that takes `self` as its first argument).

Answer (score 2):

Usually the way you define a function that's an attribute of an object is to make it a method:

```
class Proxy:
    def __init__(self, app: Flask):
        self._app = app

    def run(self) -> None:
        WSGIServer(('', 8000), self._app).serve_forever()

app = Flask(__name__)
proxy = Proxy(app)  # this calls the __init__ method defined above
proxy.run()         # and this calls the run method with "self" = "proxy"
```

Comment: Hi Sam,

The python code I'm working with doesn't like it when the flask_app is being definined in the __init__(self) function. Is there a way to make it work while having flask_app defined in the body of the class?

Comment: Doing a quick browse of Flask tutorials, it looks like the idea is generally that you have a single Flask instance?  I'll modify it to work that way.

Answer (score 0):

```
import flask
import gevent

class: Proxy
    def __init(self):
        ''' 
        *stuff*
        '''

        flask_app = Flask(__name__)
        http = WSGIServer(('', 8000), flask_app)

        self.run = lambda: (
            self.logger.critical('LISTENING %s%s' % (host, port)) or
            #flask_app.run(host=host, port=port) 
            http.serve_forever()
        )

proxy = Proxy()
proxy.run()
```

Thanks everyone for your contributions, they helped me figure it out.